# Can we print the counter values Jmeter when running via command prompt?

Tags: jmeter

This is the Jmeter script for the application.

```
1. Validate username
2. Validate Password
If controller
    Counter Variable + 1
    3. User Info
    4. Settings
    5. Payments
    etc...
    20. Logout
```

After Login, I have created counter variable and incremented the number..

I wanted to print the counter so that when running command prompt along with

Active: 15 Started: 15 Finished: 0 summary.. etc.

During the run, I wanted to give the number of logged in user.. Is there any way to print the counter value so that i can give the logged in user count?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below to print output to cmd line. Put whatever logic you want and use OUT.println to print it to CLI console.

[image]

Hope this helps.